# CXInsifht on Docker YML file error: parsing /gcxi_temp/docker-compose.yml: yaml: line 10: did not find expected key

Tags: microstrategy, genesys

while trying to install CXinsight for docker in Centos 8 I got the following error:
"parsing /gcxi_temp/docker-compose.yml: yaml: line 10: did not find expected key"

I have no idea/experience regarding the YML file. Appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Note that I'm trying to create containers using the .yml file and getting the said error.

The content of the .yml file is below:

```
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  gcxi_postgres:
  mstr_log_01:
  mstr_shared:
networks:
  gcxi:
services:
  # ## old version of gcxi-postgres service
  # ## contains built-in sample gim db, but requires 4 gb image gcxi_postgres
   gcxi-postgres:
     image: gcxi_postgres
     hostname: gcxi-postgres
     volumes:
     - "gcxi_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
     ports:
     - "5432:5432"
     networks:
     - gcxi
  ## new version of gcxi-postgres service
  ## postgres image + init job from gcxi_contorl image, no embedded gim db
  #gcxi-postgres:
  #  environment:
    # no password mode - for non-prod only!
    # otherwise comment this out and uncomment POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    #- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=g1n2s3s4
  #  image: postgres:13
  #  networks:
  #  - gcxi
  #  ports:
  #  - "5432:5432"
  #  volumes:
  #  - "gcxi_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  #gcxi-control:
  #  command: ["sleep 10 && /genesys/gcxi/run_init.sh"]
  #  depends_on:
  #  - gcxi-postgres
  #  environment:
  #  - RUN_MODE=kube
  #  image: gcxi_control
  #  networks:
  #  - gcxi
  gcxi-0:
    # legacy notation is mstr-01, compatibility preserved
    hostname: gcxi-0
    image: gcxi
    ipc: host
    user: root
    privileged: true
    command: ["sleep 30 && /genesys/gcxi/mstr_start.sh || sleep 5000"]
    # multi-line command example (create web app redirection / => /MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb)
    # command:
    # - |
    #   mkdir -p /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    #   cat <<-EOF > /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp
    #   <%
    #   response.sendRedirect("/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb");
    #   %>
    #   EOF
    #   chown -R genesys:root /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    #   /genesys/gcxi/mstr_start.sh
    # user: "34556:0"
    volumes:
    - "/genesys/gcxi_config:/genesys/gcxi_config"
    - "/genesys/gcxi_shared:/genesys/gcxi_shared"
    - "mstr_log_01:/mnt/log"
    # - "mstr_shared:/genesys/gcxi_shared"
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "8180:8180"
    - "34952:34952"
    depends_on:
    - gcxi-control
## If you need to use your own GIM DB (instead of built-in that comes as part of above container) then uncomment lines below that use single # (starting with line that says environment)
## Make sure that variables are correctly populated otherwise you will see "exited with status 1" error
    environment:


### DSN Variables ###

    ## DSNDEF* is a new DSN definition format suitable for GCXI v. >= 9.0.010.00
    ## If at least one DSNDEF* variable is defined, GIM_* variables are ignored
    ## Each DSNDEF node represents one DSN definition
    ## As of GCXI v. 9.0.010.00 DSN_NAMEs must be predefined:
    ## GCXI_GIM_DB = for project GCXI / CX Insights
    ## IWD_DB = for project IWD
    ## DSNs defined with other names will be created in MSTR, but not used by default
    ## Password notice: if GIM password contains semicolon, it must be escaped with \
    ## Eg: PASSWORD=my;passwd;.. => PASSWORD=my\;passwd;..
    ## NB: password notice does not apply to old GIM_* DSN format, no need to escape anything there
    ## For DB_TYPE and DB_TYPE_EX values see explanation in GIM section

    ## password may be passed as a separate variable
    ## if needed you could put it in a Kubernetes secret or in a secret volume mount
    ## NB: empty PASSWORD variable is still required in DSNDEF definition
    - DSNDEF1=DSN_NAME=GCXI_GIM_DB;DRV_TYPE=JDBC;JDBC_OPTS=options=-cstatement_timeout=1740000;GCXI_QENGINE=ON;DB_TYPE=POSTGRESQL;DB_TYPE_EX=PostgreSQL;HOST=gi2-qadb;PORT=5432;DB_NAME=gim85test2voice;LOGIN=gim85test2voice;PASSWORD=
    - GCXI_GIM_DB__PASSWORD=gim85test2voice

    ## example for IWD DB connection
    # - DSNDEF2=DSN_NAME=IWD_DB;DB_TYPE=POSTGRESQL;DB_TYPE_EX=PostgreSQL;HOST=gi2-cent7-2;PORT=5435;DB_NAME=gim;LOGIN=gim_db;PASSWORD=gim_db

    ## example with ODBC_OPTS
    # - DSNDEF3=DSN_NAME=ODBCOPTS_DB;DB_TYPE=SQLSERVER;DB_TYPE_EX=Microsoft SQL Server 2012;HOST=gi2-qadb;PORT=1433;DB_NAME=gim85test2voice;LOGIN=gim85test2voice;PASSWORD=gim85test2voice;ODBC_OPTS=AlternateServers=mysrv|LoginTimeout=20

    ## example for a connection with arbitrary name to MS SQLServer
    - DSNDEF4=DSN_NAME=SQLSERVER_DB;DB_TYPE=SQLSERVER;DB_TYPE_EX=Microsoft SQL Server 2012;HOST=gi2-qadb;PORT=1433;DB_NAME=gim85test2mm;LOGIN=gim85test2mm;PASSWORD=gim85test2mm

    ## example for Oracle ODBC
    # - DSNDEF5=DSN_NAME=ORACLE_DB;DB_TYPE=ORCLW;DB_TYPE_EX=Oracle 18c;HOST=gi2-qadb;PORT=1521;ORCL_SNAME=qadb.us.int.genesyslab.com;LOGIN=gim85test2voice;PASSWORD=gim85test2voice;DRV_TYPE=ODBC;ORCL_ALTSRV=(HostName=db-gen-ora2.open.ru:PortNumber=1526:ServiceName=GENESISPR)

    ## example for Oracle JDBC Thin with JDBC url
    # - DSNDEF6=DSN_NAME=GCXI_GIM_DB;DB_TYPE=ORCLW;DB_TYPE_EX=Oracle 18c;HOST=gi2-qadb;PORT=1521;JDBC_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=gi2-qadb)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=qadb.us.int.genesyslab.com)));ORCL_SNAME=qadb.us.int.genesyslab.com;LOGIN=gim85test2voice;PASSWORD=gim85test2voice;DRV_TYPE=JDBC;GCXI_QENGINE=ON

    ## example for Oracle Microstrategy JDBC Driver with JDBC url
    # Since v. 100.0.030.0000
    # - DSNDEF7=DSN_NAME=GCXI_GIM_DB;DB_TYPE=ORCLW;DB_TYPE_EX=Oracle 18c;HOST=gi2-qadb;PORT=1521;JDBC_URL=jdbc:microstrategy:oracle://gi2-qadb:1521|ServiceName=qadb.us.int.genesyslab.com;ORCL_SNAME=qadb.us.int.genesyslab.com;LOGIN=gim85test2voice;PASSWORD=gim85test2voice;DRV_TYPE=JDBC;GCXI_QENGINE=ON

    # JDBC_URL example for Oracle Microstrategy JDBC Driver with SSL/TLS
    # Since v. 100.0.030.0000
    # JDBC_URL=jdbc:microstrategy:oracle://gi2-qadb:2484|ServiceName=qadb.us.int.genesyslab.com|EncryptionMethod=ssl|Truststore=/genesys/gcxi_shared/certificates/oracle.jks|TruststorePassword=genesys01|CryptoProtocolVersion=TLSV1,TLSV1.1,TLSV1.2|ValidateServerCertificate=true


    ## A set of vars to use non-default (not 'public') schema for meta db
    ## This implies that you already have ready-to-use meta and hist dbs, residing under 'my' schema
    # - META_DB_SCHEMA=my
    # - META_DB_ODBC_OPTS=InitializationString=SET SEARCH_PATH to 'my'
    # - META_HIST_ODBC_OPTS=InitializationString=SET SEARCH_PATH to 'my'
    # - PGLOCK_CONN_OPTS=sslmode=disable&search_path=my
 

    ## MSTR odbc.ini file override
    ## if you need DSN configuration more complicated than DSNDEF provide,
    ## you can place full DSN definition(s) in DSN_ODBCINI variables
    ## they will be parsed by the container and upserted into /var/opt/MicroStrategy/odbc.ini
    ## NB: you'll still need to create corresponding DSNDEF variable for this DSN
    # - |
    #   DSN_ODBCINI=
    #   [ODBC Data Sources]
    #   GCXI_GIM_DB=MicroStrategy ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL Wire Protocol

    #   [GCXI_GIM_DB]
    #   ApplicationUsingThreads=1
    #   ...


### File Helpers ###

    ## FILEDEF* variable family allows to modify files inside the container
    ## for now supports upserts in property files
    # - FILEDEF1=FILE=/opt/tomcat/webapps/MicroStrategy/WEB-INF/xml/sys_defaults.properties;DATA=requestTimeOut=1800;MODE=upsert;PHASE=beforeTomcat;TYPE=properties

    ## FILEOVR* variable family allows to overwrite (or create if not exists) a file completely
    ## FILEOVR*__DATA is supplementary variable for convenient injection of multiline values
    # - FILEOVR1=FILE=/var/opt/MicroStrategy/env/LDAP.sh;PHASE=beforeIServer
    # - |
    #   FILEOVR1__DATA=
    #   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    #   MSTR_LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION=1
    #   export MSTR_LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION
    #   MSTR_LDAP_PASSWORD_COMPARE=0
    #   export MSTR_LDAP_PASSWORD_COMPARE
    #   MSTR_LDAP_REFERRALS=1
    #   export MSTR_LDAP_REFERRALS
    #   MSTR_LDAP_SEARCH_LIMIT=5000
    #   export MSTR_LDAP_SEARCH_LIMIT
    #   MSI_LDAP_NO_LDAP_GROUP_TO_MSTR_USER=0
    #   export MSI_LDAP_NO_LDAP_GROUP_TO_MSTR_USER
    #   MSTR_KERBEROS_SPECIAL=0
    #   export MSTR_KERBEROS_SPECIAL


### MSTR TLS ###

    # - MSTR_ISRV_ConfigureSSL=1
    # - MSTR_ISRV_SSLPort=39321
    # - MSTR_ISRV_CertificatePath=/tmp/gcxi/cert.pem
    # - MSTR_ISRV_KeyPath=/tmp/gcxi/key.pem
    # - MSTR_ISRV_KeyPassword=derparol


### Other Container Variables ###

    # - ACCESS_RESTRICTION=static
    # - GCXI_ENVS_CUSTOM=MSTR_PRJ_MAXNOREPORTRESULTROWS=3200010;MSTR_PRJ_MAXSCHEDULEREPORTEXECTIME=1233
    ## Localization: comma-separated list of locales
    # - LANGS=de-DE,ar-SA

    ## MSTR Library URL
    ## As Library access goes thru browser link, set your real (not container's) MSTR host and web port
    # - MSTR_EXTURL=http://gi2-cent7-4:8080
    # - MSTR_FONT_NAME=Vivaldi
    # - MSTR_PRJ_MAXUSERSESSIONSPROJECT=499
    # - MSTR_PRJ_MAXINTERACTIVESESSIONSPERUSER=18
    # - MSTR_SRV_MAXNOCLIENTCONNS=300
    # - MSTR_SRV_IDLETIME=1599
    ## login mode codes as of MSTR 2021:
    ## Standard (user name and password): 1 (default)
    ## LDAP Authentication: 16
    ## Trusted Authentication Request aka SAML SSO: 64
    # - MSTR_WEB_DEFAULT_LOGIN_MODE=16
    # - MSTR_WEB_DISABLE_WAIT_PAGE=true
    # - MSTR_WEB_LDAP_ON=true
    ## since 9.0.019.00 login thru SAML is supported thru container variables
    # - MSTR_WEB_SAML_ON=true
    # - MSTR_WEB_SECURE_COOKIE=true
    # - MSTR_WEB_SPLASH_TEXT=MyText
    # - MSTR_WEB_VALIDATE_RANDNUM=true
    # - SECURITY_FILTER_ON=true
    # - STAT_DB_ENABLED=1
    # - STAT_DB_DSN=mstr_stat
    # - STAT_DB_TYPE=SQLSERVER
    # - STAT_DB_TYPE_EX=Microsoft SQL Server 2012
    # - STAT_DB_HOST=gi2-qadb
    # - STAT_DB_PORT=1433
    # - STAT_DB_NAME=mstr_stat
    # - STAT_DB_LOGIN=mstr_stat
    # - STAT_DB_PASSWORD=mstr_stat
    # - TEST_GCXI=true
    # - TEST_IWD=true
    # - TOMCAT_ADMINPWD=dfe%64u)ff(ckf
    # - TOMCAT_MAXCONN=9999
    # - TOMCAT_MAXSESS=499
    - TOMCAT_NOINFO=true
    # - TOMCAT_CATALINAOPTS=<custom catalina / java opts>
    # Values: none|lax|strict
    # - TOMCAT_COOKIEPROC=lax
    # - TOMCAT_HTTPHEADERSECFILTER=true
    # - DEV_ERR_EXIT=false
    # - DEV_JTRACE_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - DEV_PRINT_MEM=false
    - DEV_XTRACE_LEVEL=OFF
## If set, automated daily backups will be done in the beginning of this hour(s) (24-hr format).
    # - BACKUP_HOUR=6,22
    networks:
      gcxi:
        aliases:
        - gcxi-0
        - GCXI-0
```